# Creating a custom component in JavaScript that works when created dynamically too

Tags: javascript

I have created a custom number input in JavaScript. Now I just need to write:

```
<input type="text" class="input-number">
```

When the pages loaded two additional buttons are added to the all text inputs with class `input-number`. The problem is if I add the text input dynamically I won't get my custom number input. What should I do?

Comment: What you have posted is not an example of a Web Component.

Comment: So what should I call it?

Comment: Better idea: why not just use `<input type=“number”>` and use its built-in up/down buttons?

Comment: I'll think about it. But you didn't say what should I call it?

Comment: "*When the pages loaded two additional buttons are added to the all text inputs with class `input-number`.*" - please post the code that does that. "*What should I do?*" - just call that code again when you are adding inputs dynamically?

Comment: Just call it what it is, which is a “dynamically added HTML input”